# Efficient read and write of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sparse-matrix, countvectorizer

I have a pandas dataframe that I want to split into several smaller pieces of 100k rows each, then save onto the disk so that I can read in the data and process it one by one. I have tried using `dill` and `hdf` storage, as csv and raw text appears to take a lot of time.

I am trying this out on a subset of data with ~500k rows and five columns of mixed data. Two contains strings, one integers, one float and the final one contains bigram counts from `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer`, stored as a `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix` sparse matrix.

It is the last column that I am having problems with. Dumping and loading the data goes without issue, but when I try to actually access the data it is instead a pandas.Series object. Secondly, each row in that Series is a tuple which contains the whole dataset instead.

```
# Before dumping, the original df has 100k rows.
# Each column has one value except for 'counts' which has 1400. 
# Meaning that df['counts'] give me a sparse matrix that is 100k x 1400. 

vectorizer = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(analyzer='char', ngram_range=(2,2))
counts = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['string_data'])
df['counts'] = counts

df_split  =  pandas.DataFrame(np.column_stack([df['string1'][0:100000],
                                               df['string2'][0:100000],
                                               df['float'][0:100000],
                                               df['integer'][0:100000],
                                               df['counts'][0:100000]]),
                                               columns=['string1','string2','float','integer','counts'])
dill.dump(df, open(file[i], 'w'))

df = dill.load(file[i])
print(type(df['counts'])
> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
print(np.shape(df['counts'])
> (100000,)
print(np.shape(df['counts'][0])
> (496718, 1400)    # 496718 is the number of rows in my complete data set.
print(type(df['counts']))
> <type 'tuple'>
```

Am I making any obvious mistake, or is there a better way to store this data in this format, one which isn't very time consuming? It has to be scalable to my full data containing 100 million rows.

Comment: How did you create/append the `counts` column?

Comment: I added this to the code

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to store a sparse matrix as a pandas column - IMO it's an error prone way. I'd store them separately...

Comment: Why do you mean it is error prone? Can you give details on why you mean it is a bad idea?

Comment: Just re-read your own question: `when I try to actually access the data it is instead a pandas.Series object` ;-)

Comment: Ok, more specifically then, do you know why it does this transformation of the data into a pandas.Series object?

Comment: because Pandas column == Pandas.Series. Pandas DataFrame is a collection of columns (Pandas Series objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['counts'] = counts
```

this will produce a Pandas Series (column) with the # of elements equal to `len(df)` and where **each element** is a sparse matrix, which is returned by `vectorizer.fit_transform(df['string_data'])`

you can try to do the following:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(counts.A, columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names(), index=df.index)
```

**NOTE:** be aware this will explode your sparse matrix into densed (not sparse) DataFrame, so it will use **much more** memory and you can end up with the `MemoryError`

**CONCLUSION:**
That's why I'd recommend you to store your original DF and `count` sparse matrix separately

Comment: Thanks, indeed the size exploded. I will separate the two as you suggested.

Comment: @Tobias, glad it helped :)